# How do I calculate dimension and base of $v$ if $A\cdot v=0$ and $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0& 2& -1\\ 2& 1& -1 \end{pmatrix}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I calculate dimension and base of $v$ if $A\cdot v=0$ and $A=\begin{pmatrix}  0&  2& -1\\   2&  1& -1 \end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: "How do I calculate dimension and base of $v$...": Are you interesed in the set $\{v \in \mathbb R^3 \mid Ax=0\}$? And you want to prove that this set forms a vector subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ and find its dimension and one of its basis?

Answer (score 2):

Hint ( I suppose $A:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$):

Let 
$$
x=\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^3
$$
we have:
$$
Ax=0 \quad \iff \quad
\begin{bmatrix}0&2&-1\\2&1&-1
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}2y-z\\2x+y-z
\end{bmatrix} =0
$$
 that is equivalent to:
$$
\begin{cases}
2y-z=0\\
2x+y-z=0
\end{cases}
$$

solve this system and you have the $\operatorname{Ker} A$.

Comment: But the thing is I need to find dimension and basis of Ker A?